# Php dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I get `[jobNo]` using loop from array below?

```
Array
(
    [date] => 2014-01-13
    [totcomdraft] => 400
    [comdraft] => 0
    [0] => Array
        (
            [jobNo] => 1401018618 
            [dateType] => 1
            [comdraft] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [jobNo] => 1401018615
            [dateType] => 1
            [comdraft] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [jobNo] => 1401018617
            [dateType] => 1
            [comdraft] => 100
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
  if(is_array($val)){
    echo $val["jobNo"];
    echo "<br />";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for( $i = 0; $ < count($array); $i++ )
{
      print $array[$i]['jobNo'] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with array in-built function :-

```
$result_array=array_map(function($input_array) 
               { 
                 return $input_array['desired_column']; 
               },$input_array_original
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
  if(is_array($val)){  // check this value in array
    echo $val["jobNo"];
    echo "<br />";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. I have tested.

```
$array = array
(
    'date' => '2014-01-13',
    'totcomdraft' => 400,
    'comdraft' => 0,
    '0' => array
    (
        'jobNo' => 1401018618, 
        'dateType' => 1,
        'comdraft' => 200
    ),

    '1' => array
    (
        'jobNo' => 1401018615,
        'dateType' => 1,
        'comdraft' => 100
    ),

    '2' => array
    (
        'jobNo' => 1401018617,
        'dateType' => 1,
        'comdraft' => 100
    )
);

for($i=0;  $i<3; $i++){
    echo 'Job no:' . $array[$i]['jobNo']."<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
Job no:1401018618
Job no:1401018615
Job no:1401018617
```